# How to delete all stored Credit card #'s except the ones from within the last month?

Tags: magento-1.9, delete, credit-card

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We have credit card numbers stored. We need to delete them (for security reasons) but we would prefer to keep the numbers from within the last month just in case there be any charge backs etc.

What is the best way to do that?